# is there any name for this style of video editing?

Tags: editing

Here is the style:

A person is talking in a certain setting and a certain dress, let's say for 10 seconds, and when he finishes his first sentence there is cut and after the cut, the same person is in a different setting and different dress but continues with his 2nd sentence. The viewer gets impression that it was a complete sentence spoken.